# Google text to speech translator api

Tags: java, google-text-to-speech

I used google text to speech translator api to translate some extracted text from an image with the following code

```
public class TranslatorApi {

    public String gettranslation()
    {

    Translator instance = Translator.getInstance();
    Translator translate = Translator.getInstance();
    String text = translate.translate("I am programmer", Language.ENGLISH, Language.TAMIL); 
    System.out.println(text);
    return  text;
    }

}
```

And then I get the following error which is displayed in the tomcat server

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://tra
nslate.google.com.br/translate_a/t?client=t&text=I%20am%20programmer&hl=en&sl=en
&tl=ta&multires=1&prev=btn&ssel=0&tsel=0&sc=1
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLCo
nnection.java:1839)
```

I have added gtranslateapi-1.0.jar and jl1.0.jar.Does anybody know a reason?
**Updated Question**

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://translate.google.com.br/translate_a/t?client=t&text=I%20am%20Bimla&hl=en&sl=en&tl=fr&multires=1&prev=btn&ssel=0&tsel=0&sc=1
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1839) at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1839)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
    at com.gtranslate.utils.WebUtils.source(WebUtils.java:24)
    at com.gtranslate.parsing.ParseTextTranslate.parse(ParseTextTranslate.java:19)
    at com.gtranslate.Translator.translate(Translator.java:37)
    at MainJFrame.jComboBox1ActionPerformed(MainJFrame.java:159)
    at MainJFrame.access$100(MainJFrame.java:19)
    at MainJFrame$2.actionPerformed(MainJFrame.java:59)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(JComboBox.java:1258)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(JComboBox.java:586)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(JComboBox.java:622)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicComboPopup.java:834)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:290)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3322)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$1.processMouseEvent(BasicComboPopup.java:498)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://translate.google.com.br/translate_a/t?client=t&text=I%20am%20bimla&hl=fr&sl=fr&tl=en&multires=1&prev=btn&ssel=0&tsel=0&sc=1
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1839)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
    at com.gtranslate.utils.WebUtils.source(WebUtils.java:24)
    at com.gtranslate.parsing.ParseTextTranslate.parse(ParseTextTranslate.java:19)
    at com.gtranslate.Translator.translate(Translator.java:37)
    at MainJFrame.jComboBox1ActionPerformed(MainJFrame.java:159)
    at MainJFrame.access$100(MainJFrame.java:19)
    at MainJFrame$2.actionPerformed(MainJFrame.java:59)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(JComboBox.java:1258)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(JComboBox.java:586)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(JComboBox.java:622)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicComboPopup.java:834)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:290)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3322)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$1.processMouseEvent(BasicComboPopup.java:498)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

in the above full stack trace is shown

Comment: The HTTP return code of 403 means you are **unauthorized** to use that URL.

Comment: How can I get the authorization?

Comment: Here's one place to start: [Google Text to Speech](https://gist.github.com/alotaiba/1728771).  You can Google "Google Text to Speech" just like I did.

Comment: I don't need audio section.I just need to translate a text in one language to another. How can I use this API for that functionality?